# cider - during and after second fermentation

Tags: cider

I've just started making my first batch of cider. Using the magnum cider starter kit. Here's the link for instructions so you can see what im doing.. 
http://www.home-brew-online.com/magnum-cider-kit-instructions-i50

I'm onto the second stage fermentation now and a bit confused on what to do next as the instructions are a bit unclear.

I've transferred ot over into pressure keg and added the 60g of sugar, now it's saying to leave it for around five days and then 'cool to clear'.. what exactly does this mean?
Will it ever stop fermenting in the keg?
Can I store keg in spare fridge in garage to keep cool and ready to drink as and when I need or will this affect the cider?
And can I travel with keg in the car to friends houses etc, or will this disturb segments on bottom if there is any?

Sorry to bombard you with questions but I've search high and low on forums all evening to try and find the answer to these questions

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Cool to clear is cold crashing.  Drop the temperature as quickly as possible to just above freezing for a few days.  This causes anything in suspension to drop out.  5 days to carbonate seems a bit quick though.

Yes, you can store the keg to keep cool.  Yes, if you travel it will most likely stir up the trub.

Comment: Thankyou!  How long would you suggest leaving it to carbonate? And is there anyway to remove the 'trub'?

Comment: 2 weeks at fermentation temperatures is the usual rule of thumb for bottle carbonating.  Regarding removal of the trub there's no way of removing it completely but if you cold crash your fermentation vessel prior to racking the cider into your keg the majority of the trub will settle to the bottom.  Be careful when racking off and you'll leave most of it behind.